# Characterization of loops on a cone that are ellipses?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

*[I re-wrote the question, so Christian's answer becomes obsolete. Sorry for that.]*

---

Consider uncollapsable closed curves on a cone (of reflection) of a given length that pass through a given point and have minimal $\oint_\gamma |\dot{\kappa}|\>ds$ ($\kappa$ = curvature) among all loops of the same length going through the same point.

If the distance of the point to the apex is $\sqrt{2}$ and the given length is $2\pi$, the curve will be a circle.

By which arguments might be told that these curves are exactly the ellipses (as cone sections, which I assume they are) without calculating them?

(How might parabolas and hyperbolas come out as such curves?)

Comment: Do you mean a cone of revolution ?

Comment: Yes, fixed it..

Comment: In the future, please do not re-write questions in ways that make existing answers obsolete, as this is a disservice to the answerer(s) who put time into responding. Instead, post a separate question, and add a link from the old question to the new one (and maybe vice-versa, if readers might find value in the previous formulation).

Comment: @Blue: You are right, and I already apologized. In the future, I'll take care.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by "overall curvature" the total curvature of a loop $\gamma$, i.e., the integral $\oint_\gamma \kappa_g\>ds$, then this total curvature is the same for all loops around the apex, by the Gauss'-Bonnet theorem, and can be expressed by the total Gaussian curvature of the cone, which is concentrated at the apex. It seems therefore that all loops are "equators" according to your definition.

Comment: This would be bad! Can you give me a hint how to pin down those equators that turn out to be ellipses? (What I had in mind initially: Take a loop of a given length, lay it around the apex, fix one of its points and let gravity take  control. How will the loop end up? (Probably not as a ellipse.))

Comment: @HansStricker: if the loop offers no resistance to flexion (like a catenary), curvature does not matter. So this new problem is different.

Comment: I assumed, too, that it's a different problem. The problem of my question is: Which subset of loops gives ellipses? (I hoped it were all loops with  minimal curvature but these seem to be *all*.)

Comment: Isn't it about the minimal overall change rate of the curvature (with distinguishes the circle, because it's 0)? What's the name of this measure?